# How to split a txt file efficiently?

Tags: java

I have a txt file and the size of it is larger than 1GB, each line has a record. Now I want to split this file to 100 txt files according to record.hashcode()%100, how can I do it efficiently?

each record has different length,efficient here are time and memory

Comment: What do you mean efficiently? Are you thinking of reading/writing in different chunks in different threads?  Are the records fixed length or variable length?

Comment: what _efficiently_ here? Memory? doing in parallel?

Comment: What does `record.hashcode` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try to read and write at the same time by using `BufferedReader`. As I know it works good for big files.

The main Idea is to read line and immediately write it to other file. You can get bad performance only if you get too long line.

(*Don't use it for binary files!*)

```
int maxlinesNumber = 1000; // I took it randomly, 
BufferedReader rd = null;
BufferedWriter wt = null;

try {
  rd = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream("/yourfile.txt"), "UTF-8")
              );

 int count = 0;

for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    if (count++ % maxlinesNumber == 0) {
        close(wt);
        wt = new BufferedWriter(
                   new OutputStreamWriter(
                      new FileOutputStream(
             "/newSmalfile" + (count / maxlinesNumber) + ".txt"), "UTF-8")
              );
    }
    wt.write(line);
    wt.newLine();
 }
} finally {
close(wt);
close(rd);
}
```

About exact count of files, I think you lose here efficiency to calculate small file size should be.

You can try to use the same way but read bytes instead lines. But this is direction.

Comment: Do you thing is it OK to get 1GB file into Buffer?

Comment: @Ketan yes, but if data is not binary. for binary data you can try `BufferedInputStream`. But it based how many chars in line .....

Comment: @Ketan added description to the header of post

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing before. They key to performance is (well was for me, as I was writing to a SAN over the network) to parallelise the writes.  Even if your read is sequential, it's probably not too bad.

Basic algorithm:

1. Create an ExecutorService, with a bounded number of threads.
2. Create a map to hold all the output files
3. Open the output files, create a Writer and add them to the map, with keys from 1..100
4. Read each line from the input in a loop, and add it as a task in the Executor
5. in the task, which runs in a separate thread from the reader, parse the line, compute the hash, lookup the file, synchronise on the file so other threads don't stomp you, then write the line
6. close all the files

viola

Gotchas:

1. When the input queue to an executor service gets full then bad things happen, depending on how it's configured.  Also an un-bounded queue is not good either.
2. The synchronising on the file objects doesn't look great, but I once tried an alternate approach which made sure there was one thread per file and so no locking was required, but it was no faster than the ExecutorService approach, so in the end it wasn't worth the effort.